Receiving "Bad Request" error with an HTTP error code of 400
I'm trying to execute an automated task through the Google Calendar API and receiving the following error message:
C:\Users\Documents\Calendar Add-On>python calendar_v2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Documents\Calendar Add-On\calendar_v2.py", line 68, in <module>
    create_events(calendar_id)
  File "C:\Users\Documents\Calendar Add-On\calendar_v2.py", line 46, in create_events
    events_result = service.events().list(
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 938, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?timeMin=2024-05-15T20%3A43%3A15.671352&timeMax=2024-06-14T20%3A43%3A15.671352&singleEvents=true&alt=json returned "Bad Request". Details: "[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'badRequest', 'message': 'Bad Request'}]">

I can't seem to figure out why it's giving me this error message.
I've tried playing around with the code a lot but always coming back to this issue. A brief snippet of my code (I've obviously omitted the calendar ID and .json file name):
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Define the service account credentials
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = r'path_to_service_account_file.json'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']

# Authenticate and build the Calendar API client
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

# Function to add buffer before and after each event
def add_event_buffer(event):
    start_time = event['start'].get('dateTime')
    end_time = event['end'].get('dateTime')
    
    if start_time and end_time:
        start_dt = datetime.fromisoformat(start_time)
        end_dt = datetime.fromisoformat(end_time)
        buffer_time = timedelta(minutes=10)
        buffered_start_time = (start_dt - buffer_time).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
        buffered_end_time = (end_dt + buffer_time).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
        event['start']['dateTime'] = buffered_start_time
        event['end']['dateTime'] = buffered_end_time
        event['summary'] = 'Travel Time - ' + event['summary']
        
    return event

# Function to create buffered events on the calendar
def create_buffered_events(calendar_id):
    try:
        start_time = datetime.now().isoformat()
        end_time = (datetime.now() + timedelta(days=30)).isoformat()
        events_result = service.events().list(
            calendarId=calendar_id,
            timeMin=start_time,
            timeMax=end_time,
            singleEvents=True
        ).execute()
        
        events = events_result.get('items', [])
        if not events:
            print('No events found.')
        else:
            for event in events:
                if 'Travel Time' in event.get('summary', ''):
                    print(f'Skipping buffered event for: {event["summary"]} (already buffered)')
                    continue
                buffered_event = add_event_buffer(event)
                if 'id' in event:
                    service.events().update(calendarId=calendar_id, eventId=event['id'], body=buffered_event).execute()
                    print(f'Buffered event updated for: {buffered_event["summary"]}')
                else:
                    service.events().insert(calendarId=calendar_id, body=buffered_event).execute()
                    print(f'Buffered event created for: {buffered_event["summary"]}')
    except Exception as e:
        print("An error occurred:", e)
        raise 

# Example usage
if __name__ == '__main__':
    calendar_id = 'calendar_id@gmail.com'
    create_buffered_events(calendar_id)


Please narrow down the problem or specify it precisely. What call is failing? service.events().list(), service.events().update(), or service.events().insert()? Log all data and check it is correct. Let us know what data you are passing to the failing call. Look at the sample code provided elsewhere and compare it with yours. You may even ask ChatGPT to generate a snippet for you and see if it works and what the differences are.

Hhow would I know which call is failing? I couldn't find a sample code elsewhere and this was generated using ChatGPT. This is all very new to me so I may need some assistance.

Add logs to your code and trace to the failing call. Log data too.

You may start from this example: https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/python
Then try adding this code: https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/create-events

In your script, how about the following modification? Please modify create_buffered_events as follows.
From:
start_time = datetime.now().isoformat()
end_time = (datetime.now() + timedelta(days=30)).isoformat()

To:
start_time = datetime.now().isoformat() + "Z"
end_time = (datetime.now() + timedelta(days=30)).isoformat() + "Z"


When I tested your script, I confirmed the same error message. And, when I tested the script reflected the above modification, no error occurred, and the event was updated.


THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!! This worked for me! I can't believe it was as simple as that!

Hi @Tanaike, sorry but my code is running into an issue again. Can I please request if you can quickly take a look for me?
https://github.com/danishik/random/blob/main/calendar

@Danish Karmally About your new question of Hi @Tanaike, sorry but my code is running into an issue again. Can I please request if you can quickly take a look for me?, I would like to support you. So, can you post it as a new question by including more information? By this, it will help users including me think of a solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?
